# Will the JIT inline private field access from another class?

Tags: c#, properties, jit, inlining

I have some properties used to access fields from a parent class like so:

Class A:

```
private int _number = 42;
public virtual int Number { get { return _number; } }
```

Class B : A:

```
public override int Number { get { return base.Number + 1; } }
```

My question is, if I access `B.Number`, will it still resolve to a direct access to `A._number` (+ 1)?

This is assuming an optimized Release build, of course.

More importantly, are access modifiers abstract (as in they only matter when compiling and do not have an impact on code when running), or will they actually restrict access at runtime (other than when using Reflection, of course)?

Comment: Specifically for this case I am unsure.. however, I do know that the JIT inlines automatic property assignments from within the same class (don't ask me to find the reference for that), since they are just method calls with a single line in them (therefore, easily "inline-able"). I'm unsure how inheritance plays into that scenario though.

Comment: Given that the property is still virtual, the JIT *can't* inline an access of `B.Number` to a simple field access. It might if you seal it - but if you really care about it, you should probably break out the debugger and look at the assembly code to check. It may differ on x86 from x64.

Comment: I can see why that would be, but couldn't it detect that nothing overrides the property in classes derived from B and make it automatically seal the property? And if someone _does_ override it and still calls `base.Number`, couldn't that call still be inlined?

Comment: A better title for this question is *Will the JIT inline private field accesses exposed through virtual properties?*

Answer (score 0):

Well they are abstract in the sense that they don't affect runtime performance but the information still needs to be stored in the compiled IL for cases where e.g security manager is enabled.

And no, the call to the getter function here wasn't inlined in x64 nor x86.

```
public static void Main(string[] args) {    
     B b = new B();
     int a = b.Number;
}
```

You can use [these instructions](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vancem/archive/2006/02/20/535807.aspx) to disassemble the jitted code and see for yourself too.